# how can i show 2 intro views when the app is launching?

Tags: iphone, xcode, image

I know if there is a file named Default.png it shows the image automatically.
but, I want to change the image during it showes.
FYI, I have 2 images Default.png and default2.png.
I want to display default2.png after show Default.png.
I tried followed codes, but it didn't work.
What do I have to do?

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

//..................................................................
//self.window bullabulla~

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showIntro2View) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
//[self showIntro2View];  //also tried this, but not work.

[self.window addsubview:tabbarController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
-(void) showIntro2View {
UIImageView *intro2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initwithframe:cgrectmake(0,0,320,460)];
intro2.image = [UIImage imagenamed:@"default2.png"];
[self.window addSubview:intro2];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:intro2];
[NSThread sleepfortimeinterval:2];
}
```

Comment: why are using performSelectorOnMainThread ?? you are already in the main thread ! , can you tell us what is the result of this code ?

Comment: just show the mainview. I also tried [self showIntro2View] instead MainThread with sleepcode, but it was same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `APP DELEGATE`.
Something like this should do the job:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds] autorelease];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NAMEOFYOURSPLASHSCREEN.png"];
    imageView.image = image;
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self performSelector:@selector(remove1stSplash:) withObject:imageView afterDelay:5];
    return YES;
}

- (void)remove1stSplash:(UIImageView *)1stView {
    UIImageView *imageView = ...
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(remove2ndSplash:) withObject:imageView afterDelay:5];
    [1stView removeFromSuperView];
}

- (void)remove2ndSplash:(UIImageView *)2ndView {
    [self.window addSubview:.....
    [2ndView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Link for a sample project:
[Two Splash Screen display in iphone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/two-splash-screen-display-in-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, you don't have real influence on how long the Default img is displayed. But you know when it shows and hides. It shows only, when the app runs the first time, the app is not in background or has been terminated after a while of not using it.

The first View Controller that is called, should implement `viewWillAppear`, as it is something like the last method called before the default image hides. There everything is loaded and you can immediately add a subview to the main window.

I'd do it in 2 different methods like `showOverrideDefaultImage` and `hideOverrideDefaultImage`. In the show method you add your own View to the appDelegate window and fire a

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideOverrideDefaultImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

In the hide method simply remove your view from superview. Therefore you have to have a valid pointer to this object.

that's it. Don't use NSThread.

Comment: the problem when I implement in the viewWillAppear, I'm using tabbarController and navigationController, the intro image shows in the tabbar and navigationbar.

Comment: yes you should show the image in the app delegate window like so: `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:yourSubview];` Paste this in the show method in your view controller. That should be above all the other views.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 -(void) showIntro2View 
{
  UIImageView *intro2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initwithframe:cgrectmake(0,0,320,460)];
  intro2.image = [UIImage imagenamed:@"default2.png"];
  intro2.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"default2.png"], nil];
  intro2.animationDuration = 2.0f;
  intro2.animationRepeatCount = 0;
  [intro2 startAnimating];

  [self.window addSubview:intro2];
  [self.window bringSubviewToFront:intro2];
  [NSThread sleepfortimeinterval:2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks~! I'm gonna try this next time.